# Jquery help needed - 2 Clicks 2 functions

Tags: jquery, click, hamburger-menu

i have a hamburger menu. This is how it looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <label for="toggle" class="bigmac">&#x2630;</label>
```

I used a symbol for the icon. I want to change the icon when clicking on it to a other icon, a cross. And when i click again, to close the menu, change it back to the hamburger.

I tried a lot but have no idea how to do this using the "toggle".

This what i have in jquery to change it to the cross:

```
$( ".bigmac" ).click(function(){
    $( ".bigmac").html("&#x2715;")
})
```

But how do i let it change back when clicking again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class `cross` into the `.bigmac` element so that you can have a `if-else` condition setup accordingly to get toggle effect:

```js
$( ".bigmac" ).click(function(){
   if($(".bigmac").hasClass('cross')){
     $(".bigmac").html("&#x2630;").removeClass('cross');
   } else {
     $(".bigmac").html("&#x2715;").addClass('cross');
   } 
})
```

```css
.cross{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle" class="bigmac">&#x2630;</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to style your button using css and add active class to the button on click.
For example (not tested yet):

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    if ($("#btn").hasClass("active")) {
        $("#btn").removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $("#btn").addClass("active");
    } 
})
```

Comment: Cant style my button in css, i use Unicode for the buttons, so i need to change the html. But thank you for your awnser

Comment: Did you try css with content property?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use  `toggle` for this.

```js
$('.bigmac').toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('&#x2630;');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).text('&#x2715;');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle" class="bigmac">&#x2630;</label>
```

Comment: When i use toggle the icon goes invisible, but i already got the awnser, thank you!